# After multiplying two column i am getting nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, multiplication

I am not expecing `nan` value; how I can solve this error?

```
UNITS = {"KG/HA":1, "L/HA":1, "G/HA":0.001, "ML/100KG":0.001, "G/L":0.001}
i = df["DOSAGE"]
u = df["DOSAGE_UNIT"]
df['NEW'] = i.map(UNITS) * u
#print(df.head())
df = df['NEW']
print(df)
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Output:

```
0        NaN
1        NaN
3        NaN
4        NaN
6        NaN
        ... 
24287    NaN
24288    NaN
24289    NaN
24290    NaN
24291    NaN
Name: NEW, Length: 19243, dtype: object)
```

Comment: Please provide the original dataframe

Comment: See [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Just using the variable names, I'd bet on `i * u.map(UNITS)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['NEW']=i * u.map(UNITS) #it works
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).